# Separation of sets $A$ and $B$ given continuous functions vanishing on $A$ and not on $B$

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on the following qual problem:

> Suppose $X$ is a compact topological space and $A,B \subset X$ are closed.  Suppose also that for each $b \in B$, there exists a continuous function $f_b : X \to [0,1]$ sending $A \mapsto \{0\}$ and $b \mapsto 1$.  Show that there are disjoint open sets $U \supset A$ and $V \supset B$.

Here is my solution:

> For $b \in B$, define disjoint open sets $U_b=f_b^{-1}[0,1/3)$ and $V_b=f_b^{-1}(2/3,1]$.  Then $A \subset U_b$ and $b \in V_b$.  Now, $\{V_b\}_{b \in B}$ is an open cover of $B$, which is compact because it is a closed subset of a compact space.  So it has a finite subcover, say $\{V_{b_i}\}$.  So let $U=\bigcap_i U_{b_i}$ and $V=\bigcup_i V_{b_i}$.

What bothers me is I haven't used the fact that $A$ is closed.  Am I missing something, or is this a redundant assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything: the assumption is redundant, and your argument is correct. However, if $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then $X$ is Tikhonov, and the existence of the functions $f_b$ follows from the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are closed; whoever posed the question may have had that in the back of his mind.